# Performing Operations on Multi-Indexed data based on Indices

Tags: python, multi-index

I have a 2 level multi-indexed (on X and Y) data frame that looks like this:

```
df=(
    X1   Y1   Z1
              Z2
         Y2   Z3
              Z3
              Z4
    X2   Y3   Z5)
```

And I want to do some operation on Z based on the values of X and Y. So, I have written:

```
for x in df.index.levels[0]:
    for y in df.index.levels[1]:
        Do something on Z
```

However, I am getting the outcome irrespective of values of X and Y.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the setup from the multiindex pandas page:

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
      ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)
print(s)
```

output s:

```
                0         1         2         3
bar one -2.252251 -0.655827  1.463011 -0.028378
    two  0.764846  0.245175 -0.580668 -1.054938
baz one  1.052068 -0.024946  0.435709  0.067140
    two  0.397881  0.658192 -1.178750 -0.137875
foo one  0.168246  0.391718  1.001085 -0.353019
    two -0.034458 -1.182889  0.207794  0.275627
qux one -1.236448  0.258419  0.999734 -0.774948
    two -0.518770  1.954563 -1.627627  0.436150
```

0, 1, 2, 3 would be your "Z"

So say I wanted to access each of the rows where the 2nd index is 'one', we can use df.xs():

```
s.xs('one', level=1)+1
```

returns (we added 1 to each column where the second index = 'one'):

```
            0         1         2         3
bar -1.252251  0.344173  2.463011  0.971622
baz  2.052068  0.975054  1.435709  1.067140
foo  1.168246  1.391718  2.001085  0.646981
qux -0.236448  1.258419  1.999734  0.225052
```

Now say I wanted to access both second indexes where the first index = 'bar' and square this value:

```
s.xs('bar', level=0)**2
```

returns squared values of index 'bar' for both second index 'one' and 'two':

```
            0         1         2         3
one  5.072636  0.430109  2.140401  0.000805
two  0.584989  0.060111  0.337175  1.112894
```

Level=0 corresponds to your 'X', level=1 corresponds to your 'Y', and values correspond to your 'Z'. I hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks. But, my main question is how do we iterate through the items in multi-indexed list and do an operation based on a given values in different index levels? e.g. 'for x in ['bar,'baz]: for y in ['one,'two']: z=f(x) * f(y)

Comment: The x and y shouldn’t be indexed if you want the function to operate on them mathematically, indexes are generally labels... but I guess numbers could be labels for other numbers.